# Angular JS Bootstrap Dropdown Typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

[PLUNKR EXAMPLE](https://plnkr.co/edit/qAnTuxbxq7nGzsc221IT?p=preview)

I'm trying to set up a dropdown typeahead in AngularJS, but I'm having a few problems.

1) The options don't update even when the $scope variable specified in ng-options changes.

2) The dropdown arrow is very far to the right of the typeahead box itself.

How can I fix these issues?

ANGULAR CODE:

```
<script>
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('StateSelectCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.states = [{
    name: 'Georgia'
  }, {
    name: 'Illinois'
  }, {
    name: 'Nevada'
  }, {
    name: 'New Jersey'
  }, {
    name: 'California'
  }];

  $scope.button = function() {
    $scope.states = [{
    name: 'Florida'
  }, {
    name: 'New York'
  }, {
    name: 'Missouri'
  }, {
    name: 'Ohio'
  }, {
    name: 'Oregon'
  }];
    console.log($scope.states);
  }
})

.directive('combobox', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch("selectedState", function () {
                    if (!scope.comboboxSetup) {
                        $(".combobox").combobox();
                        scope.comboboxSetup = true;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="StateSelectCtrl">
        <h2>Device ID:</h2>
        <select combobox class="combobox input-large" ng-model="selectedState" ng-options="state.name for state in states">
          <option disabled value="">Select a Device</option>
        </select>
          <button ng-click="button()">Click me</button>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    //$(document).ready(function() {
      //$('.combobox').combobox()
    //});
    //]]>
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Well, I suggest you to use [**angular-ui#/typeahead**](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead). Here's a working [**code**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBJaVE).

Comment: I need it to be a dropdown as well

Comment: I can't see the difference between the typeahead and that combobox.. By the way, I saw what's the difference.. typeahead you don't need to do a custom directive and also you can access easily the `ngModel`. That combobox maybe creates a `child scope`.. I don't know.

Comment: The typeahead doesn't let me click on it and scroll through all the options like a html `<select>` box does.

Comment: Here's a version working with this feature: [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qdt66xbFFYQh3AdCxXaG?p=preview). Using pure `css`.

Comment: I still have to type something before I can see any options.

Comment: But using that combobox you also have to do this..

Comment: [Example of combobox](http://bootstrap-combobox-test.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: Why is your plunker so different of this?

Comment: Because I've tried to set it up in AngularJS. But my plunker also lets you see the options by clicking on the arrow, which, for some reason is all the way on the right of the page

Comment: That's the problem.. it will give too many headache to work on Angular. That's why I'm suggesting another approach.

Comment: I need it to be Angular though, the rest of the website is all Angular

Comment: That's why I'm suggesting you to use Angular-ui instead of this hack solution with combobox.

Comment: Is there any way to offer the drop down feature using Angular-UI? I need to have both

Comment: Take a look [**here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/AS612yj2gKcwGYffAipr?p=preview). There are all options of `typeahead`, choose which best meets your requirements.

Comment: You can also use [angular-material#autocomplete](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete).

Comment: Hi Nishant, Have you gotten a solution? I am facing the same problem